# Sonar and LDAP. Unable do login

Tags: authentication, ldap, sonarqube

I'm trying to configure the sonar to login with LDAP without success.

```
Here is my sonar.properties

sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=true
ldap.url=ldap://ad01.mydomain.com:389
ldap.baseDn=dc=mydomain,dc=br
ldap.bindDn=CN=Test User,OU=User,OU=!State,OU=!RJ,DC=mydomaind,DC=com
ldap.bindPassword=some.pass
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.baseDn=OU=User,OU=!State,OU=!RJ,DC=mydomain,DC=com
ldap.realm=mydomain.com
ldap.loginAttribute=mail
```

I set de log level to FULL and when I try login with a domain account this message show up in the log file.

```
SELECT * FROM `properties` WHERE (((`properties`.`resource_id` IS NULL AND `properties`.`user_id` IS NULL)) AND (`properties`.`prop_key` = 'sonar.allowUsersToSignUp')) LIMIT 1
```

Ldap plugin 1.4

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using SonarQube 3.7.3 and I attached my configuration which works. I hope that would be useful.

```
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
sonar.security.savePassword=true
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=true
ldap.url=ldap://...
ldap.bindDn=user
ldap.bindPassword=password

# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=People,dc=company,dc=local
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
```

Comment: Thanks Eddú. With you configuration sample I realized my mistake. The baseDN was wrong.

Comment: Joao if the answer heps you. Can you mark as a correct answer, please?